# A property of dual norm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In the convex optimization textbook, page 475, Stepend Boyd defines the normalized steepest descent direction with repect to the norm $||.||$ as

$$ \Delta  x_{nsd} = argmin \{ \bigtriangledown f(x)^T v \; | \; ||v|| \leq 1 \}$$

In the Appendix A of this book, the dual norm is defined as
$$ || \bigtriangledown f(x) ||_{\ast}  = \sup \{  \bigtriangledown f(x)^T v \; | \; ||v|| \leq 1 \}$$

I tried many ways to figure out the following conclusion
$$\bigtriangledown f(x)^T  \Delta  x_{nsd}  = - || \bigtriangledown f(x) ||_{\ast} $$

Unfortunately, I have not figured out any potential solution. Do you have any solution or suggestion to help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: @user251257 : The thing I do not understand here is that $\Delta x_{nsd}$ is a vector while $argmin \{ \bigtriangledown f(x)^T v \; | \; ||v|| \leq 1 \}$ is a number. P/S: I am only a undergraduate student and I am sorry if there is a stupid thinking.

Comment: No. argmin means the minimizer which attains the minimum value.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. now I see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT** It boils down to understanding the dual norm.  This dual norm has the nice property that 
$$ |\bigtriangledown f(x)^Tv|\leq\|\bigtriangledown f(x)^T\|_*\|v\| $$
for any vector $v$. So when $\|v\|\leq1$ we have
$$ |\bigtriangledown f(x)^Tv|\leq\|\bigtriangledown f(x)^T\|_* $$
Then you need to figure out when equality is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed,

$$\Delta x_{\text{nsd}} = \underset{\|v\| \le 1}{\text{argmin }}\langle \nabla f(x), v\rangle = \underset{\|v\| \le 1}{\text{argmax }}\langle -\nabla f(x), v\rangle.$$
Thus, $\langle -\nabla f(x), \Delta x_{\text{nsd}}\rangle = \max_{\|v\| \le 1}\langle -\nabla f(x), v\rangle =: \|-\nabla f(x)\|_* = -\|\nabla f(x)\|_*$, where the first equality is by the optimality of  $\Delta x_{\text{nsd}}$, and the second is by the definition of the dual norm. Conclude.

Comment: $||- \nabla f(x)||_{*} \neq -|| \nabla f(x)||_{*}$